# Not getting full HTTP response from HttpClient

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I do not seem to be getting the entire json response from httpclient.  I am hitting an api I'm running locally like so:

```
curl -i -X POST http://localhost:8098/<api location> -F "files=@<filename>"
```

And my response looks like this:

```
{"data":[<bunch of json>]
```

But when I try to post the exact same file with httpclients, I get this response:

```
{"data":[]}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Here is my java code.  Thank you!

```
public CloseableHttpResponse submit (File file) throws IOException {
    CloseableHttpClient client = HttpClients.createDefault();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(API_LOCATION + API_BASE);
    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.addBinaryBody("ISO xml file", file, ContentType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM, file.getName());
    HttpEntity multipartEntity = builder.build();
    post.setEntity(multipartEntity);

    CloseableHttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    System.out.println("response: " + IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent(),"UTF-8"));
    client.close();
    return response;
}
```

Comment: In curl you name the field `files`, but in Java you name it `ISO xml file`. Since server only looks for `files`, it see nothing, and responds with nothing.

Comment: What about the parameter's name? On curl you used 'files' and on http client you used 'ISO xml file'. Try changing it to 'file'.

Comment: I changed "ISO xml file" to "files" and it worked.  I did not realize the significance of that field - I thought it was just for identification.  What is the significance of the string at the end of that line, then?  The string that I populated with file.getName()???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Andreas and Danilo mentioned in the comments:

> In curl you name the field files, but in Java you name it ISO xml file. Since server only looks for files, it see nothing, and responds with nothing. - [Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902048/not-getting-full-http-response-from-httpclient/51902184#comment90755281_51902048)
>
> What about the parameter's name? On curl you used 'files' and on http client you used 'ISO xml file'. Try changing it to 'file'. - [Danilo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902048/not-getting-full-http-response-from-httpclient/51902184#comment90755302_51902048)

I needed to change "ISO xml file" to "files" and it worked.